# Pass a set function as an argument

Tags: apache-flex, function

How can I pass a 'set' function as the Function Object argument of another function?
eg:

```
public class IdModel
{
    private var _id:String;

    public function IdModel(source:Source)
    {
        //Create Binding
        BindingUtils.bindSetter(id,source,"id");

    }

    public function get id():String
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public function set id(value:String):void
    {
        _id = value;
    }
}
}
```

In the example above the 'id' argument is being evaluated and returning a String, so it won't compile with the error: "String is not assignable to argument of type Function".

Thanks

Comment: Referencing "id" will call it's getter.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi James, as Markus points out below in this particular case I could use bindProperty, but I want to encapsulate the id property because in my actual code the 'set' function carries out some work on the value it is passed. Markus's second solution does the job by the looks of things, is this the price we pay for the nicety provided by the 'get' and 'set' keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case you don't need to; you can use `BindingUtils.bindProperty` instead:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(this, "id", source, "id");
```

But if you really want to use bindSetter and a function you can probably do:

```
BindingUtils.bindSetter(function (arg:*): void { id = arg; }, source, "id");
```